# Objective C annotation views are slow to show up after touch

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

I've got a simple map view that displays info from a JSON service.

I've got it plotting the pins and adding annotations just fine, but I've noticed that the pins require me to press on them and hold my finger there for a second before they show up.

Is there any way to make them respond to a normal touch? Is this standard functionality or should I look for something capturing the event or something in my code?

Comment: Could you post your code that represents the annotation-actions?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're blocking main thread with your service, but without code it's just an assumption. Also custom views/gesture recognizers could cause such a behavior.